# How do I add a DLL to GAC

Tags: c#, .net, global-assembly-cache

This is my code:

```
Register(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).Location);

private void Register(String assemblyName)
{
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("D://gacutil.exe", string.Format("/i {0}", assemblyName));
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    System.Diagnostics.Process process= System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo);
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

How do I add the DLL to the assembly Folder?

Comment: Your code looks good. What is the error ?

Comment: `gacutil.exe` exists in `D` ?

Comment: i check assemply folder but new dll file not exsists

Comment: yes @SriramSakthivel in D

Comment: You have to put the entire assembly path

Answer (score 6):

You have to put the entire assembly path for this to work.
For example

```
gacutil /i D:/someassembly
```

Rest of your code looks fine. Just use whole assembly path instead of just assembly name.

Answer (score 3):

[MSDN Publish.GacInstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enterpriseservices.internal.publish.gacinstall.aspx)

Use `GacInstall()` method in the `Publish` class to GAC the assembly easily. 
Add reference to `System.EnterpriseServices`. Please make sure particular dll is [Signed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Only signed assembly can be added to GAC.

```
private void Register(String assemblyName)
  {
      Publish publish = new Publish();
      publish.GacInstall(assemblyName);
  }
```

Comment: i use this code it works but i can not found created dll file

Comment: @IslamIbrahim what do you mean by created dll file ? you meant you couldnt see the dll in the GAC folder ?

Comment: I want my dll show when add reference in any project with .Net Component List

Comment: @IslamIbrahim If you want to GAC an assembly that dlls should be signed. Please check if you have done that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need either to set the working directory of teh process to your current working directory or to send the full path of the .dll