# C# How to add my dll to .Net Framework Component List

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-framework-version

[image: .Net Framework component list]

I want add my dll to component list with dlls as shown in image
How to do this by **C# code**

Comment: Go to the "browse" tab and search for your DLL

Comment: i know this, but i want to know how to add dll to this list

Comment: @voo how to do this By c# code

Comment: TO add using c# code (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569367/c-sharp-how-to-add-dll-to-gac)

Comment: @voo - GAC has *nothing* to do with this tab.

Answer (score 3):

The content of the .NET tab is determined by registry settings.  You can easily change them:

- Start Regedit.exe
- Navigate to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders key (drop Wow6432Node on a 32-bit machine)
- Right-click the AssemblyFolders key, New + Key
- Type a distinctive name, like the product or your own name.  The actual string doesn't matter
- Double-click the (Default) value in the right pane and type name to the *directory* that contains your assemblies
- Restart Visual Studio

A sample .reg file that will add the folder, edit it for your own use:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\Hans Passant]
@="C:\\Users\\hpass_000\\Projects\\ClassLibrary1\\bin\\Release"
```

Comment: Use the RegistryKey class.  This is not a great idea, you cannot write to that registry key unless your program runs elevated and you can't make sure that VS is restarted.

Comment: Wouldn't it work to _always_ ommit the WoW6432Node/ part from the reg key? System folder redirection should kick in automatically and redirect to the WoW version on 64bit? Edit: ok, should read the post first ;) This is about manual edits... nevermind!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on toolbar, select choose Items and add your dll through browse button

Comment: i know this, but i want to know how to add dll to this list

Comment: Try adding that to GAC

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.

1. Sign your dll.
2. Put your dll inside your framework folder.

Sample:

Copy your dll to this folder

```
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
```

Not matter if the Proyect that will Reference Dll is open.
 Try to add Reference and you will see your dll.

Hope this help.